# Accessing JSON returned from AJAX object in jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm new to jQuery. I'm trying to get some data from MySQL via AJAX. My PHP returns JSON. This is the response (don't mind variables names. It's in Czech :)):

```
  [{"nadpis":"Testovac\u00ed nadpis","text":"Testovac\u00ed \u010dl\u00e1nek o tom jak se zase prohr\u00e1lo","sestava":"Nikdo nehr\u00e1l"},{"nadpis":"Druhej nadpis","text":"Druhej text","sestava":"druh\u00e1 sestava"}]
```

Here is my jQuery function:

```
 $.ajax({ type: 'GET',   
                 url: 'db.php',   
                 datatype:'json',
                 success : function(data)
                 {  console.log(data[1].text);
                    console.log(data);
                 }
        });
```

The problem is that when I want to access data[1].text, it only returns *undefined*. I went through a lot of answers here on StackOverflow and other forums, but I still can't make it work.

Comment: If that's the `second` array in your return, then it's simply `data[1]['text']`

Comment: @Ohgodwhy there's no effective difference between that and what's in the OP.

Comment: Yeah, that's very true. So that further bets the question, what does the structure of `data` look like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `datatype` to `dataType`. Otherwise jQuery doesn't recognize the option and won't parse the response for you.

In your case, `data` is still a string, which you can verify with `console.log(typeof data)`. `data[1]` returns `"{"`, and `"{".text` is `undefined`.

Have a look at the documentation for the correct option names: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

---

Alternatively, you could [parse the response yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4935632/218196).

<sup>*(I posted an answer to prevent other misguiding answers. It's community wiki because I voted to close the question.)*</sup>

Comment: Thank you .). It works now. Such a stupid mistake. I've spent half a day trying to solve it and all I need is uppercase T :D